# Using generic function for drawing line d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3js to draw a multiline chart.

My function to draw line is below.

```
meanLine = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('linear')
            .x(function (d) {
                return xScale(d.date);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return yScale(d.mean);
            });

//data is declared at top
group.append('svg:path')
            .attr({
                d: meanLine(data),
                "stroke": "rgba(" + color + ", 0.8)",
            });
```

Here the value of date and mean is hardcoded. I want a generic function to which I can pass which value to use for drawing line.

I want something like

```
lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('linear')
            .x(function (d, xval) {
                return xScale(d[xval]);
            })
            .y(function (d, yval) {
                return yScale(d[yval]);
            });

//data is declared at top
group.append('svg:path')
            .attr({
                d: lineFunc(data, xval, yval),
                "stroke": "rgba(" + color + ", 0.8)",
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this... here `myLineFun` houses your `d3 line function`:

```
//make a function which houses the line function
var myLineFun = function(data, xval, yval){
        //the line function
        var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('linear')
            .x(function (d) {
                return xScale(d[xval]);//xval passed in the argument
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return yScale(d[yval]);//yval passed in the argument
            });
        return lineFunc(data);//this will return the d attribute
}
```

And then call this:

```
group.append('svg:path')
            .attr({
                d: myLineFun(data, xval, yval),
                "stroke": "rgba(" + color + ", 0.8)",
            });
```

Hope this helps!